# Android studio - edittext

Tags: java, android, android-studio, edittext

Нужно сделать EditText таким, чтобы он был многострочным, но при этом в длину был "бесконечным".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
    <EditText 
    ...
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    ...
    />
```

UPD:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Shwarz Andrei, данный метод не подходит, так как не соответствует условию. Строчек много, но они короткие, то есть они такой же длины, как экран.

Comment: А, нет, не помогает(

Comment: Вообще не выходит. Пробовал и вашим способом и включить single line, но ничего (

Comment: @Miu-MiuHaskeer, а как Вы представляете реализацию того, чтобы строка была большей длины, чем экран? Ведь получается, что в этом случае буквы должны висеть в воздухе...)

Comment: Я хочу чтоб было так, как в этом ответе на гифке, но ничего не выходит(